# Remove element from a static List<MyClass>

Tags: c#, list, static

I've some problem with the method `List<T>.Remove(T)`. I've a class (described down) that is used as Type for a List.
My class is:

```
public class MyClass
{
   public string ID { get; set; }
   public myEnum CallType { get; set; }
   public object ObjToStore { get; set; }
}
```

and my `List<T>` is instantiated like this:

```
private static List<MyClass> ListOfStoreObjects = new List<MyClass>();
```

My trouble is that I store the stuff into these lists and I can't remove them. I use those lists to store temporary data in a web service (I want to 'walk this way', so please don't tell me other solutions, thx) and of course, once those data were used I've to manage to remove them from this "buffer". So, there is a way to remove an element from a static list?

## Edit

The add function that I use is:

```
public bool AddToQueue(string id, myEnum callType, object objToAdd)
{
   try
   {
      MyClass elementToAdd = new MyClass();
      elementToAdd.ID = id;
      elementToAdd.CallType = callType;
      elementToAdd.ObjToStore = objToAdd;
      ListOfStoreObjects.Add(elementToAdd);

      return true;
   }
   catch
   {
      return false;
   }
}
```

The function that I use to retrieve the object that I need and then delete it from the list:

```
 public object RetrieveObj(string id, myEnum callType)
 {
     object obj = null;

     foreach(var element in ListOfStoreObjects)
     {
         if( element.ID == id && element.CallType == callType)
         {
             obj = element.ObjToStore;
             break;
         }
     }

     MyClass itemToRemove = new MyClass();
     itemToRemove.ID = id;
     itemToRemove.CallType = callType;
     itemToRemove.ObjToStore = obj;

     ListOfStoreObjects.Remove(itemToRemove);

     return obj;
 }
```

Comment: And why do you have problems with `Remove`? What isn't working as expected?

Comment: what is the problem, thread related or anything else?

Comment: @MightyBadaboom the problem is that actually when I call List<T>.Remove(T) on my list, it doesn't work, it doesn't delete anything.

Comment: @ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ What do you mean? I can't understand you question...

Comment: And you guess we can help you when you won't give us any information? At least we need the code you are using or an exception message?

Comment: @Mighty Badaboom mmh you're right, but actually I don't get any Exception code. I can't debug the code of the web service (where the code that I wrote above is used) because is already publish. But anyway tell me if you need some extra info, for example the call sequence that I execute. Anyway I'll add now the piece of code that use the `.Remove(T)`...

Comment: How are you removing, adding that code will help, as you may be removing a copy and not actual item!

Comment: @Anil I've edited the question, let me know now with these more information what's wrong... if there's something wrong XD

Comment: Actually you are removing a new item that does not exist in the list, so you need to put an hack here refer @Karolis answer for this. Try  `itemToRemove  == sameIdItemfromList` or `itemToRemove.Equal(sameIdItemfromList)` for further understanding `IEqualityComparer`

Comment: Mmmh, It does make sense. So I can use the `.Remove(T)` depending on the index of the ID that I'm looking for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are removing the object incorrectly. You have to remove it like this:

```
public MyClass RetrieveObj(string id, myEnum callType)
{
     MyClass obj = null;

     foreach(var element in ListOfStoreObjects)
     {
         if( element.ID == id && element.CallType == callType)
         {
             obj = element;
             break;
         }
     }
     ListOfStoreObjects.Remove(obj);

     return obj;
}
```

This is a very common mistake. You are finding the correct object and instead of using that instance, you are creating a new object of the class which will **never** match with any object in the list.

**Alternate Solution**

Sharing a simpler one-line way of doing what you are trying to do:

```
ListOfStoreObjects.RemoveAll(x => x.ID == id && x.CallType == callType);
```

Comment: It gave me an sintax error because I can't cast an `object` into a `MyClass`

Comment: Update the function definition's return type to `MyClass`. I've updated the answer with the same change.

Comment: Ok, it seems working pretty well. I've used the one-line way, easier and faster to implement haha. Anyway, if I just want to delete the first result of the expression I've to use the other code that you wrote, am I right?

Comment: Ok, I can confirm that both ways works fine. So I'll mark this as solution for my problem, but also the other asks were very interesting

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement `IEquatable<T>` which is used internally by generic `List<T>` collection to determine equality of a custom type.

Here is an example (given `ID` is your unique indentifier):

```
public class MyClass : IEquatable<MyClass>
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public myEnum CallType { get; set; }
    public object ObjToStore { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(MyClass x)
    {
        return x.ID.Equals(this.ID);
    }
}
```

[More about the interface.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131190(v=vs.110).aspx)

**EDIT**

You create a new object which does not share referential equality with object you try to remove. Approach provided above will do the trick but it is not the cleanest solution for your case.

I would suggest removal by `index` and that is only if you so much prefer to use `List` instead of `HashSet`:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < ListOfStoreObjects.Count; i++)
 {
     if( ListOfStoreObjects[i].ID == id && ListOfStoreObjects[i].CallType == callType)
     {
         ListOfStoreObjects.RemoveAt(i);
         break;
     }
 }
```

Why `RemoveAt` instead of `Remove`? `Array` as an underlying collection of `List`, does `O(1)` lookup of elements by index, thus for this type of collection it is the most efficient way of removing items due to semantics of how array resolves in memory.
Also, if you would look into .NET source `Remove` method will loop once again through the `collection` and remove element calling `Equals` method to check equality.

Comment: I'll try it soon, but for now I'll suggest you to look at my edit of the question. I've added the Add method that I use and also the method where the `.Remove(T)` fail. Thanks anyway for now, I'll tell you if it will work.

Comment: Defining `IEqualityComparer<T>` alone [won't make](https://dotnetfiddle.net/A7F3CX) `List<T>.Remove()` work as expected. `IEquatable<T>` should be implemented for that.

Comment: @DmitryEgorov Oh my... Shame on me. I knew that HashCode shouldn't be there. It is used for bucketed collections rather than index based. Thanks for pointing this one out! Made correction.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally `Remove()` should work and is a better and the right way to do this. You should try and figure out why you aren't using it correctly. But if you still aren't able to you could try something like this. You should replace `st.IsCompleted` with another condition to indicate that the item is *not* to be removed. Please note that this is not as efficient as `Remove()` and is only meant as a workaround.

```
ListOfStoreObjects = ListOfStoreObjects.Where(st => st.IsCompleted).ToList();
```

Comment: I'll use this workaround if I'll not came up with another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since you create a new instance of `MyClass` when invoking `List<T>.Remove()`, you have to implement `IEquatable<T>` to tell the `Remove` to compare IDs (and maybe other properties) instead of just object references when looking for the collection item to remove

Implement `IEquatable<T>` interface in `MyClass`:

```
public class MyClass : IEquatable<MyClass>
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public myEnum CallType { get; set; }
    public object ObjToStore { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(MyClass other)
    {
        return other != null && other.ID == this.ID;
    }
}
```

From [List<T>.Remove documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1):

> If type T implements the IEquatable generic interface, the equality
>   comparer is the Equals method of that interface; otherwise, the
>   default equality comparer is Object.Equals.